# getting undefined when looking for res.data.fullName...but can access data in console

Tags: mongodb, react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElFCR.png)not sure why I cant access the data in the console.
no problem accessing using res.data but as soon as I type res.data.fullName or any of the properties...it says undefined
using react native.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxszX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your call returns an array of objects, you should be able to access them with:

```
.then(res => {
    for (const data of res.data) {
        console.log(data.fullName);
    }
})
```